# How to activate the sliding menu bar which is below the main MENUBAR

Tags: javascript, html, css

Guys i have a sliding menu bar which is getting hide below the main menu bar
I have tried with all the property but unable to do so. The sliding menu bar should be top of the main menu bar so that the scrolling of sub-menu could take place.

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 40px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
    
    *{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
 /*To hide the horizontal scroller appearing during the animation*/
 overflow: hidden;
}

#clouds{
 padding: 100px 0;
 background: #c9dbe9;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
 background: -linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
}

/*Time to finalise the cloud shape*/
.cloud {
 width: 200px; height: 60px;
 background: #fff;
 
 border-radius: 200px;
 -moz-border-radius: 200px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
 
 position: relative; 
}

.cloud:before, .cloud:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute; 
 background: #fff;
 width: 100px; height: 80px;
 position: absolute; top: -15px; left: 10px;
 
 border-radius: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
 transform: rotate(30deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
 width: 120px; height: 120px;
 top: -55px; left: auto; right: 15px;
}

/*Time to animate*/
.x1 {
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}

/*variable speed, opacity, and position of clouds for realistic effect*/
.x2 {
 left: 200px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
 transform: scale(0.6);
 opacity: 0.6; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 /*Speed will also be proportional to the size and opacity*/
 /*More the speed. Less the time in 's' = seconds*/
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
 left: -250px; top: -200px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

.x4 {
 left: 470px; top: -250px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.75; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
}

.x5 {
 left: -150px; top: -150px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}

    
   nav {
  max-width: 1500px;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  margin: -500px auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7FFFD4 0%, #7FFFD4 25%, #7FFFD4 75%, #7FFFD4 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:80px;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 18px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: rgba(0, 35, 122, 0.7);
}
    .menubar{
        position: relative;
        bottom: -100;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="clouds">
 <div class="cloud x1"></div>
 <!-- Time for multiple clouds to dance around -->
 <div class="cloud x2"></div>
 <div class="cloud x3"></div>
 <div class="cloud x4"></div>
 <div class="cloud x5"></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
</div>

    
    <div class="menubar">
    
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Java</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here you can see the output bu running it. You can see how it's getting hide?

Comment: you should tag javascript as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.open-btn{ font-size:30px;cursor:pointe; position: relative;
    z-index: 1111;}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 40px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
    
    *{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
 /*To hide the horizontal scroller appearing during the animation*/
 overflow: hidden;
}

#clouds{
 padding: 100px 0;
 background: #c9dbe9;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
 background: -linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
}

/*Time to finalise the cloud shape*/
.cloud {
 width: 200px; height: 60px;
 background: #fff;
 
 border-radius: 200px;
 -moz-border-radius: 200px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
 
 position: relative; 
}

.cloud:before, .cloud:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute; 
 background: #fff;
 width: 100px; height: 80px;
 position: absolute; top: -15px; left: 10px;
 
 border-radius: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
 transform: rotate(30deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
 width: 120px; height: 120px;
 top: -55px; left: auto; right: 15px;
}

/*Time to animate*/
.x1 {
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}

/*variable speed, opacity, and position of clouds for realistic effect*/
.x2 {
 left: 200px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
 transform: scale(0.6);
 opacity: 0.6; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 /*Speed will also be proportional to the size and opacity*/
 /*More the speed. Less the time in 's' = seconds*/
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
 left: -250px; top: -200px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

.x4 {
 left: 470px; top: -250px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.75; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
}

.x5 {
 left: -150px; top: -150px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}

    
   nav {
  max-width: 1500px;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  margin: -500px auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7FFFD4 0%, #7FFFD4 25%, #7FFFD4 75%, #7FFFD4 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:80px;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 18px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: rgba(0, 35, 122, 0.7);
}
    .menubar{
        position: relative;
        bottom: -100;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="clouds">
 <div class="cloud x1"></div>
 <!-- Time for multiple clouds to dance around -->
 <div class="cloud x2"></div>
 <div class="cloud x3"></div>
 <div class="cloud x4"></div>
 <div class="cloud x5"></div>
</div>
 
 
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  
  <span class="open-btn" onclick="openNav()"> &#9776; </span>
</div>

    
    <div class="menubar">
    
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Java</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: yes  i have change  css and html  i add  one class (. open-btn) and is css

Answer (score 1):

The button should not be inside the toggling navbar itself so I moved it out, also I created a single function (`toggleNav()`) instead of two separate function.  Here I check if the width is set, if so set it to zero, else vice versa will happen. Please use this as a template and style your code to meet your requirements, hope this solves your issue!

```js
function toggleNav() {
    
   if( document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width === "250px"){
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("closebtn").innerHTML = "&#9776;";
   }else{
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px"
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    document.getElementById("closebtn").innerHTML = "X";
   }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#closebtn{
   text-decoration: none;
}
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.menubar{
 z-index:9;
}
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 40px;
    z-index:10;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
    
    *{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
 /*To hide the horizontal scroller appearing during the animation*/
 overflow: hidden;
}

#clouds{
 padding: 100px 0;
 background: #c9dbe9;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
 background: -linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
}

/*Time to finalise the cloud shape*/
.cloud {
 width: 200px; height: 60px;
 background: #fff;
 
 border-radius: 200px;
 -moz-border-radius: 200px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
 
 position: relative; 
}

.cloud:before, .cloud:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute; 
 background: #fff;
 width: 100px; height: 80px;
 position: absolute; top: -15px; left: 10px;
 
 border-radius: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
 transform: rotate(30deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
 width: 120px; height: 120px;
 top: -55px; left: auto; right: 15px;
}

/*Time to animate*/
.x1 {
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}

/*variable speed, opacity, and position of clouds for realistic effect*/
.x2 {
 left: 200px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
 transform: scale(0.6);
 opacity: 0.6; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 /*Speed will also be proportional to the size and opacity*/
 /*More the speed. Less the time in 's' = seconds*/
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
 left: -250px; top: -200px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

.x4 {
 left: 470px; top: -250px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.75; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
}

.x5 {
 left: -150px; top: -150px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}

    
   nav {
  max-width: 1500px;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  margin: -500px auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7FFFD4 0%, #7FFFD4 25%, #7FFFD4 75%, #7FFFD4 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:80px;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 18px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: rgba(0, 35, 122, 0.7);
}
    .menubar{
        position: relative;
        bottom: -100;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="clouds">
 <div class="cloud x1"></div>
 <!-- Time for multiple clouds to dance around -->
 <div class="cloud x2"></div>
 <div class="cloud x3"></div>
 <div class="cloud x4"></div>
 <div class="cloud x5"></div>
</div>

  
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="toggleNav()" id="closebtn">&#9776;</a>
</div>

    
    <div class="menubar">
    
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Java</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: ya this is also do but I got my answer I just forgot to add z-index #main {
        position: absolute;
  z-index: 80;
}. But i must appreciate your startegy. Thanks a lot It'll help me in my near future... I'm posting the what actually i needed wait....

Answer (score 1):

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 40px;
}
    #main {
        position: absolute;
  z-index: 80;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
    
    *{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
 /*To hide the horizontal scroller appearing during the animation*/
 overflow: hidden;
}

#clouds{
 padding: 100px 0;
 background: #c9dbe9;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
 background: -linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
}

/*Time to finalise the cloud shape*/
.cloud {
 width: 200px; height: 60px;
 background: #fff;
 
 border-radius: 200px;
 -moz-border-radius: 200px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
 
 position: relative; 
}

.cloud:before, .cloud:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute; 
 background: #fff;
 width: 100px; height: 80px;
 position: absolute; top: -15px; left: 10px;
 
 border-radius: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
 transform: rotate(30deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
 width: 120px; height: 120px;
 top: -55px; left: auto; right: 15px;
}

/*Time to animate*/
.x1 {
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}

/*variable speed, opacity, and position of clouds for realistic effect*/
.x2 {
 left: 200px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
 transform: scale(0.6);
 opacity: 0.6; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 /*Speed will also be proportional to the size and opacity*/
 /*More the speed. Less the time in 's' = seconds*/
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
 left: -250px; top: -200px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

.x4 {
 left: 470px; top: -250px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.75; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
}

.x5 {
 left: -150px; top: -150px;
 
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
 transform: scale(0.8);
 opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
 
 -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
 0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}

    
   nav {
  max-width: 1500px;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  margin: -500px auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7FFFD4 0%, #7FFFD4 25%, #7FFFD4 75%, #7FFFD4 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left:80px;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 18px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: rgba(0, 35, 122, 0.7);
}
    .menubar{
        position: relative;
        bottom: -16px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="clouds">
 <div class="cloud x1"></div>
 <!-- Time for multiple clouds to dance around -->
 <div class="cloud x2"></div>
 <div class="cloud x3"></div>
 <div class="cloud x4"></div>
 <div class="cloud x5"></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
</div>

    
    <div class="menubar">
    
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Java</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
    </div> 
    </body>
```

Comment: one suggestion, when you open the sidebar, only have the `X` icon open, the other one should be hidden.

Comment: ya thanks for the suggestion it will make it more better